# Can not block torrent traffic in my Ubuntu 22.04 vps

Tags: 22.04, iptables, ufw, bittorrent, vps

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 vps which I want to block all torrent traffic on it.

I tried `Iptables` by this commands :

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "BitTorrent" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "BitTorrent protocol" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "peer_id=" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string ".torrent" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "announce.php?passkey=" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "torrent" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "announce" -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -m string --algo bm --string "info_hash" -j DROP
```

and i installed `iptables-persistent` to keep configs.

But the torrent traffic is still passing in my vps and it has caused copyright issues. recently i recived `dmca_p2p` abuse warning  and ...

**how can i block all torrent traffic in my vps ?**

Comment: Since you are merely conveying encrypted packets (P2P is usually encrypted), string filtering won't work. A similar scenario was asked and answered at https://serverfault.com/questions/27088/using-linux-iptables-how-to-block-torrents-or-any-p2p-protocols back in 2009. Some of those strategies are still quite appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

i solved this problem by this script :

https://github.com/nikzad-avasam/block-torrent-on-server

```
wget https://github.com/nikzad-avasam/block-torrent-on-server/raw/main/btorrent.sh && chmod +x btorrent.sh && bash btorrent.sh
```

will download the script, add the executable permission to the script and run the script

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1327771)

Comment: the link is not for reference . link is for a script from github and running script solves problem. script have readme